# Exception while loading wsdl using apache cxf

Tags: java, apache, cxf

I have generated the web service client from WSDL file using the apache cxf. But on loading the service class from the java client is throwing an exception as shown below. The issue here is that we are invoking this service from a different machine. So calling it as localhost wont work. Can you please suggest a solution without changing the wsdl in server.

`Also WSDL contains the xsd import as shown below.
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost/ea/AE_ARCH/Services?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>`

```
    javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initialize(ServiceImpl.java:163)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:129)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:82)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.tempuri.StudyManagementService.<init>(StudyManagementService.java:39)
    at com.ge.med.xed.provider.data.plugin.ea.wcf.EAConnectorTestApp.initializeAndSearchFromEA102(EAConnectorTestApp.java:36)
    at com.ge.med.xed.provider.data.plugin.ea.wcf.EAConnectorTestApp.main(EAConnectorTestApp.java:22)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:87)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:218)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initialize(ServiceImpl.java:161)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException (at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema): faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'http://localhost/ea/AE_ARCH/Services?xsd=xsd2'.: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2198)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(WSDLReaderImpl.java:830)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(WSDLReaderImpl.java:654)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseTypes(WSDLReaderImpl.java:610)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseDefinitions(WSDLReaderImpl.java:320)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2352)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2338)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:236)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:163)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:85)
```